# Designing a one EVERYTHING search box (date+address+keywords)

Tags: search, search-engine, search-box

**I'm storing information about local "events". They are described by 3 things - address, date, keywords(tags). I want to have only one search box for at least address and keywords.** The date might go to a separate field. I'm assuming that most people will search for events that are taking place "today" so this filter won't get that much traffic.

I need those addresses to be correct (because I'm geocoding them afterwards) so I need to validate them before submitting the form and display a list of "did you mean" if a user made a typo there. I can't do life search here. I can do a live search on keywords. Keep in mind that a user can make a typo there too and I want to catch that.

**Is there a clever way to design the input's parser in this case to guess which is supposed to be address and which keywords?**

**OR**

**Is there a way to actually parse it as user is entering his query?** Maybe I should show autocomplete hints for keywords, after 3 first characters are entered, and if user denies to use them then to assume that it's a part of an address he's typing.

What do You think?

Comment: I provided an answer to a somewhat related question asking about Google-style search keywords (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328926/implementing-search-with-google-style-site-or-is-keywords/2330013#2330013). Let me know if this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Document Cloud's Visual search

http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/#demo