# regex like gmail search operators - PHP preg_match

Tags: regex, search, gmail

I'm trying to implement a system similar to gmail search operators using function preg_match from PHP to split the input string .
Example:

**input string** => command1:word1 word2 command2:word3 command3:word4 wordN
**output array** => (
command1:word1 word2,
command2:word3,
command3:word4 wordN
)

The following post explains how to do it: [Implementing Google search operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328926/implementing-google-search-operators)

I already test it using preg_match but doesn't match. I think regular expressions may change a bit from system to system.
Any guess how regex in PHP would match this problem?

```
preg_match('/\s+(?=\w+:)/i','command1:word1 word2 command2:word3 command3:word4 wordN',$test);
```

Thanks,

Comment: pre_split instead of preg_match will do it right

Comment: Actually (at least today 2016-07-27) gmail adds parenthesis when there are special characters in a criteria: `to:(testing@test.test) subject:(testing other word) from:test`

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
<?php
$input = 'command1:word1 word2 command2:word3 command3:word4 wordN command1:word3';
preg_match_all('/
  (?:
    ([^: ]+) # command
    : # trailing ":"
  )
  (
    [^: ]+  # 1st word
    (?:\s+[^: ]+\b(?!:))* # possible other words, starts with spaces, does not end with ":"
  )
  /x', $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$result = array();
foreach ($matches as $match) {
  $result[$match[1]] = $result[$match[1]] ? $result[$match[1]] . ' ' . $match[2] : $match[2];
}

var_dump($result);
```

It will cope even with same commands at different locations (eg. "command1:" at both the start and end).

Comment: pretty cool! but this code gives a "PHP Notice:  Undefined index" message... to fix this, just use isset($result[$match[1]]) ? ... instead.

Comment: @bruno.braga yes, isset will probably fix this issue

Comment: The final regex is `'/(?:([^: ]+):)([^: ]+(?:\s+[^: ]+\b(?!:))*)/'` works fine for me, thanks