# Matching operator:term and operator: term with PHP search operators

Tags: php, regex, search, operators, preg-match-all

I am using the answer I found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897060/regex-like-gmail-search-operators-php-preg-match) to allow me to have search operators.

The one issue with it is that it requires that there are no spaces between then operator  and the words.

So it will match `operator:something` but not `operator: something` so what I am wondering is how I can match either form?

```
preg_match_all('/
  (?:
    ([^: ]+) # command
    : # trailing ":"
  )
  (
    [^: ]+  # 1st word
    (?:\s+[^: ]+\b(?!:))* # possible other words, starts with spaces, does not end with ":"
  )
  /x',
  $search, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

  $result = array();
  foreach($matches as $match) {
      $result[$match[1]] = isset($result[$match[1]]) 
          ? $result[$match[1]] . ' ' . $match[2] 
          : $match[2];
  }
```

Comment: What you have made change in the code provided by Savannah you are just asking the answer without working on this

Comment: You must post the input string and the expected output, not a link to bad written post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:\s*
```

\s is a flag for white-spaces, * means 0 or more

Answer (score 1):

4th line

```
:\ ? # trailing ":" or ": "
```